# java - socket gets closed while trying to read/send

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, socket.io, datagram

I'm trying to implement a listener to a socket, using java `DataSocket`, so I created a new listener class which gets an `ExecutorService` and run on a thread of it's own.
In the same class, I want to make another method that will also send messages through the same socket, to the same address (since that server also waits for my answers).

For some reason the socket gets closed all the time and I get an exception.

I used w `while` loop to wait for the messages, and when I get a response, I use a callback to send an answer.

This is the implementation:
This is the listener class:

```
public class MessageListener implements IMessageTransport {

    private final static int TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 300;
    private final int port = 12000;
    private InetAddress address;

    private DatagramSocket socket;

    private Executor executor;

    public MessageListener(String address, Executor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;

        try {
            this.address = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(this.address, port);
            socket.bind(sockaddr);
            socket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
        } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // todo - handle exception
        }
    }

    public void start(final MessageTransportCallback callback) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("heresa");
                listen(callback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void send(byte[] message) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("heresa");
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(byte[] message) {
        System.out.println("Sending message: " + bytesToHex(message));
        try {
            DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, this.address, this.port);
            socket.send(request);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
            System.out.println("timeout");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // todo - handle exception
        }
    }

    private void listen(final MessageTransportCallback callback) {
        DatagramPacket reply;
        System.out.println("here");

        while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                reply = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                socket.receive(reply);
                if (reply.getLength() != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Read bytes: " + bytesToHex(reply.getData()));
                    callback.onComplete(Arrays.copyOfRange(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength()));
                }
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
//                System.out.println("timeout?");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // todo - handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I send messages and start the listener:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(address, executorService);
messageListener.start(new MessageTransportCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(byte[] response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
});
messageListener.send(bytemessage);
```

Though I get a bind socket error:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:117)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:395)
    at main.MessageListener.<init>(MessageListener.java:33)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:194)
```

But the weird thing, if I send messages to the socket like this it is working:

```
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, this.address, this.port);
socket.send(request);
```

which means the socket doesn't retunr a bind error on that way, but, I cannot listen to the socket like this, and I only get messages after sending them...

and ideas why I get the `bind` error? how I can create a socket with a thread that listen to new messages and a thread that sends messages?

Comment: It looks like the exception you're getting is a port binding exception not a timeout.

Comment: @SamOrozco indeed, but why? I can send messages to that port and address if I try by the other method I mentioned.